# Barra de Progresso e Tempo

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu gostaria de saber qual é a melhor função em C# que retorna com o tempo restante em que a barra de progresso chega até o final.

Tentei isto:

```
int restante = Math.Min(progressBar1.Maximum, progressBar1.Value);
```

e isto também

```
int restante = Math.Max(progressBar1.Maximum, progressBar1.Value);
```

**mas o que consegui foi apenas o tempo que leva para completar o progresso**

Este código tinha dado certo mas agora não funciona:

```
var i=progressBar1.Maximum / progressBar1.Value * 1000;
```

mas ele diz que a divisão foi resultado zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma barra de progresso é apenas uma representação *visual* de uma escala qualquer para indicação de andamento de alguma atividade. Ela usa uma escala pra representar esse andamento, mas a informação apresentada pode ser de tempo (quando já passou x quanto falta passar), de conteúdo (quanto já foi processado x quanto falta processar), ou de qualquer outra coisa que você imaginar (até mesmo para configuração de uma variável num intervalo predefinido - muito embora ferramentas mais modernas forneçam objetos próprios para isso).

De todas as formas, a escolha do que vai ser representado fica a cargo do desenvolvedor do sistema. Apenas a "implementação" é sempre a mesma: geralmente as estruturas de dados fornecidas por linguagens como o C# para a construção de barras de progresso têm três propriedades que são usadas pra facilitar o "desenho" da barra. São elas:

- **Max**: Armazena o valor máximo da escala escolhida.
- **Min**: Armazena o valor mínimo da escala escolhida.
- **Value**: Armazena o valor atual na escala escolhida. Começa em Min e vai até Max.

Assim, considere o seguinte exemplo:

Suponha que você deseje fazer o download de um arquivo de 500 bytes (vamos chamar esse tamanho de n) e usar uma barra de progresso para indicar o andamento desse download. Ao invés de representar o "tempo" você irá representar o "tamanho" simplesmente fazendo a barra se mover conforme os bytes são baixados.

No início não terá sido baixado nada, então faz sentido imaginar que o início (a propriedade Min) será 0. Já no fim o arquivo terá sido completamente baixado, o que pode significar (dependendo de uma escolha SUA) que (A) o valor da propriedade Max será n (ou seja, 500 - o total de bytes) ou (B) 100 (equivalente a dizer que 100% do arquivo foi baixado).

Se você escolher por representar o andamento em termos diretos dos bytes (A), conforme o arquivo for baixado (em geral você captura um evento pra ser notificado do andamento do download) você contará o número de bytes já baixados (vamos chamar esse valor acumulado de i) e simplesmente atualizará a propriedade Value com o valor de i: `Value = i`.

Caso você escolha por representar o andamento em termos do percentual do arquivo baixado (B), conforme o arquivo for baixado você precisará contabilizar esse percentual, o que é facilmente calculado dividindo-se o total baixado (i) pelo tamanho original do arquivo (n), para então atualizar a propriedade Value com ele: `Value = i / n`.

Se você quer usar uma barra de progresso para fornecer uma estimativa de *tempo* de alguma tarefa, você precisa calcular por si próprio duas coisas:

1. O tempo decorrido desde o início da tarefa até o momento.
2. O "tamanho" total da tarefa e do que já foi realizado (como o número de bytes baixados do exemplo anterior).

Assim, você pode - em intervalos predefinidos - calcular uma simples regra de três pra chegar ao seguinte resultado: se você levou um tempo (t) pra processar o tamanho (i) já baixado, você então provavelmente levará um tempo (t') para processar o tamanho total (n), *se as condições de execução da tarefa se mantiverem as mesmas*.

Esse cálculo é simples. Divida o tempo decorrido (t) pelo "tamanho" já processado (i), e multiplique esse "fator" pelo tamanho total (n), usando esse resultado como o valor para Max e o tempo decorrido como valor para Value: `Max = n * t / i`  e  `Value = t`.

**Observações**:

- Deve ter sido fácil perceber que não tem milagre: você precisa saber o tamanho final da sua "tarefa" pra poder mostrar uma barra de progressos que seja condizente com a realidade. Mas isso nem sempre é factível. Imagine um programa que precisa deletar todos os arquivos com uma dada extensão em todas as pastas e subpastas de um disco muito grande. Para calcular o "tamanho" para qualquer uma das abordagens anteriores o programa precisaria primeiro percorrer todos os arquivos para contá-los, mas isso é o mesmo que fazer a tarefa originalmente intencionada e é por isso que em muitos casos não se usa uma barra de progresso e sim um mero indicador de que o programa não travou (algo apenas girando na tela sem escala alguma).
- Mesmo tendo o tamanho final da sua tarefa, a estimação de tempo muitas vezes é incerta. Por exemplo, o download de arquivos depende da banda da rede que pode variar de acordo com o tráfego existente. Por isso é uma estimativa. Geralmente não se usa barras de progresso para indicar isso de forma visual, porque pode parecer estranho ao usuário ver uma barra de progresso "andar pra trás" (no caso da estimativa piorar por latência da rede, por exemplo). É por isso que ferramentas como os programas para downloa de Torrents apresentam as duas informações: uma barra de progresso para indicar de maneira consistente o andamento do download em termos do tamanho (em bytes) do arquivo e uma informação textual dos segundos *estimados* para término (calculados de forma similar à indicada).

---

P.S.: Com base em tudo que foi explicado, a sua última linha de código certamente gera erro de divisão por zero porque o valor da propriedade Value está igual a 0, o que é natural no início de uma tarefa. Provavelment você quis fazer o contrário, e dividir o valor atual (Value) pelo máximo (Max) para obter um percentual e então aplicá-lo ao valor 1000.

P.P.S.: "Tempo restante" e "Tempo para completar o progresso" me parecem a mesma coisa. Está confuso na sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu quero uma função que retorna com o tempo restante para completar o progresso.

Comment: @Nathan130200 Como eu disse na resposta, o tempo restante precisa ser estimado a partir do seu problema. Eu tenho quase certeza que o C# não tem um função pronta pra isso.