# Melhores práticas ao apresentar tela de loading em Android

Tags: android, ux, usabilidade

A abordagem mais conhecida e difundida para  mostrar ao usuário que uma requisição à rede está acontecendo e fazê-lo aguardar até o fim desta, tem sido por meio do uso do componente `ProgressDialog`. O componente é criado no início da requisição e fechado ao final. Isto pode ser conseguido, por exemplo, utilizando uma `AsyncTask`.

Utilizando a abordagem descrita teríamos no método `onPreExecute()` de nossa `AsyncTask` algo como:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
     dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
     dialog.setTitle("Realizando o carregamento dos dados");
     dialog.setMessage("Aguarde o fim da requisição...");
     dialog.show();
}
```

E ao fim da requisição, no `onPosExecute()` da `AsyncTask`:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String retorno) {
    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    TextView dados = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.dados);
    dados.setText("Dados: " + retorno);
    dialog.dismiss();//Fecha o dialog após o fim da requisição
}
```

O produto do uso do `ProgressDialog` seria algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Embora bastante usada esta abordagem parece que se tornou uma má prática no que diz respeito a [usabilidade](https://youtu.be/pEGWcMTxs3I?t=2m6s) e aparece entre os [10 piores](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/6PwgQPMvK1p) itens que afetam a experiência do usuário.

Diante disso, pergunto: qual a melhor forma de mostrar ao usuário que uma requisição está ocorrendo? Como adaptar o código abaixo de modo a fazê-lo se adaptar as novas exigências de usabilidade?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botao);
        botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Task(v.getContext()).execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private Context context;

        public Task(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Realizando o carregamento dos dados");
            dialog.setMessage("Aguarde o fim da requisição...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String urlServico = "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlServico);
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream stream = http.getInputStream();

                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                reader.read(buffer);
                return new String(buffer);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String retorno) {
            Activity activity = (Activity) context;
            TextView dados = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.dados);
            dados.setText("Dados: " + retorno);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depende de onde você despoleta a ação: se for um botão o *Progress* pode aparecer no próprio botão, se for na *ActionBar* a mesma coisa, ao preencher uma lista pode aparecer na lista, etc.

Comment: Olá, @ramaral. Como eu faria para usar este abordagem que você destacou? Existe alguma propriedade ou método nesses componentes descritos que permita a apresentação do Progress?

Comment: Veja [isto](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-ProgressBars) e [isto](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html#actionbar_actionview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depende de onde/como você despoleta a requisição: se for um botão o *ProgressBar* pode aparecer no próprio botão, se for na *ActionBar* a mesma coisa, ao preencher uma lista pode aparecer na lista, etc.

Qualquer que seja a forma escolhida ela deve garantir que não bloqueia a tela e, se possível, permita ao utilizador sair da aplicação e voltar mais tarde para aceder ao resultado da requisição.

---

**Exemplo em que o *ProgressBar* aparece no botão.**

Crie um layout com um *Buttom* e um *ProgressBar*

***progress_buttom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/progressBarLayout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/progressButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Download" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/progressButton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/progressButton"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Substitua o seu botão, no xml da Activity, por este layout, da seguinte forma:

```
<include layout="@layout/progress_button"/>
```

O seu código ficaria assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView dados;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.progressButton);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        dados = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dados);

        botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Task().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String urlServico = "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlServico);
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream stream = http.getInputStream();

                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                reader.read(buffer);
                return new String(buffer);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String retorno) {
            dados.setText("Dados: " + retorno);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplos das outra formas que citei podem ser encontradas [aqui](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-ProgressBars) e [aqui](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html#actionbar_actionview).

Comment: Olá, Ramaral. A solução funcionou perfeitamente. Uma última questão: a prática adequada ou recomendada quando o usuário realiza uma requisição é então não "bloquear" a tela e permitir que o usuário utilize o app normalmente, é isso? Você pode incluir isso em sua resposta?

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 8):

A sua pergunta já foi muito bem respondida pelo colega @ramaral. E, aliás, o ponto principal da resposta do colega é esse:

> Qualquer que seja a forma escolhida ela deve garantir que não bloqueia
>   a tela e, se possível, permita ao utilizador sair da aplicação e
>   voltar mais tarde para aceder ao resultado da requisição.

Mas como você usou as tags [usabilidade](/questions/tagged/usabilidade) e [ux](/questions/tagged/ux), eu achei que dava pra explorar mais o assunto. Assim, eu só estou respondendo porque acho que posso colaborar adicionando algumas informações e cenários para enfatizar a colocação acima do colega. Aliás, eu não vou oferecer exemplos de código simplesmente porque a sua pergunta não vale apenas para Android, mas para qualquer plataforma, e porque esse não é o foco da minha resposta.

---

## Usabilidade na Indicação de Progresso

Exclusivamente sob o ponto de vista da usabilidade - em que se deseja que o produto seja "usável" (dai o nome "usabilidade"), isto é, fácil de utilizar, entender, aprender, memorizar, etc - o uso de telas de progresso é especialmente necessário para transmitir a informação de que o sistema não está inoperante. Em outras palavras, algo *importante* está sendo realizado e por isso o usuário deve aguardar. A palavra "importante" está destacada porque essa importância é relativa ao usuário: a tarefa é importante *para ele*, de forma que ele está disposto a aguardar seu encerramento. Um exemplo bem simples é de um aplicativo de modelagem 3D em que o artista criou todo um cenário e então solicita a [renderização](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renderiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o) da imagem ou vídeo com as animações. Essa tarefa leva tempo, o usuário está ciente disso no processo de uso do aplicativo, e aguardará o tempo necessário dentro dos limites óbvios de algo factível. Mas o aplicativo precisa demonstrar que está fazendo tal tarefa.

Uma indicação óbvia de que o processo está fazendo algo é uma animação simples. Com o uso do sistema o usuário aprende que enquanto aquela animação está em execução o sistema não está simplesmente "travado", e sim fazendo a tarefa que foi solicitada. Hoje em dia usa-se esse disco circular que você cita na pergunta, mas mesmo no passado - em que sistemas eram desenvolvidos apenas em interface textual - utilizava-se animações [com a adição de pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58453/como-fazer-efeito-de-loading-no-terminal-em-apenas-uma-linha) ou com a alternância de caracteres como esses:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além dessa indicação visual de que o processo está em execução, *idealmente* deve-se também fornecer duas informações adicionais para melhorar a usabilidade: uma estimativa de conclusão e a opção de cancelar o processo. Essas informações são importantes para que o usuário não apenas tenha informações sobre aquela tarefa que lhe é importante (critério importante de usabilidade chamado feedback), mas também para que se sinta confiante e seguro no controle da interação (outros critérios importantes da usabilidade são a segurança e a recuperação de erros).

A estimativa de conclusão pode ser oferecida na forma de um percentual (quanto já foi realizado x quanto falta realizar) ou na forma de tempo (quantos segundos/minutos/horas/dias/semanas/etc faltam para terminar), e a escolha depende do domínio do problema e dos dados para cálculo estarem disponíveis (número de itens a processar). Mas em geral (e quando possível) usa-se as duas. Um exemplo clássico é uma ferramenta de download por Torrents. Mais informações sobre o cálculo dessas estimativas podem ser obtidas [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25101/barra-de-progresso-e-tempo).

A opção de cancelar é importante principalmente em tarefas iniciadas pelo usuário porque permite que ele se recupere de erros. No exemplo do artista 3D renderizando uma cena, no caso de ele perceber que faltou ajustar algum objeto na cena ele pode cancelar o processamento para fazer tal ajuste a qualquer momento, e não precisa esperar até o final do processamento para essa ação.

Mas mesmo em tarefas que *não são* iniciadas pelo usuário, tanto o feedback de progresso como a opção de cancelamento são importantes para garantir uma utilização mais prazerosa (diferentemente de [usabilidade](/questions/tagged/usabilidade), aqui já se começa a pensar mais na experiência do usuário, ou [ux](/questions/tagged/ux)).

## Experiência na Indicação de Progresso

Quando eu disse que o ponto chave da resposta do colega @ramaral era que deve sempre ser possível ao utilizador sair da aplicação e voltar mais tarde, era principalmente pelo aspecto da Experiência. O seu sistema computacional (seja ele em utilizado no Android, no iOS, na Web, no PlayStation 4, na SmartTV, não importa) é um produto. E nada é mais desgastante para o usuário do que um produto que não permite ser utilizado como desejado.

O usuário tende a ser mais paciente com tarefas que ele solicitou ("estou disposto a aguardar por esse download que eu pedi") do que com tarefas que o seu sistema "acha" que precisa ser realizada. Eis um cenário muito real:

> Ned Stark gosta muito de assistir episódios de séries no Netflix
>   durante seu horário de almoço. Como ele trabalha de casa, o horário de
>   almoço é aquele momento de relaxamento importante pra ele (que mantém
>   sua cabeça no lugar, digamos). Certo dia, ele preparou seu almoço, sua
>   bebida, e se sentou confortavelmente no sofá ansioso por aquele novo
>   episódio de *House of Cards*. Então, ligou sua SmartTV e abriu o
>   aplicativo do Netflix, que então exibiu a mensagem: "**Há uma
>   atualização que PRECISA ser realizada agora. Por favor guarde.**". Sem
>   opção de cancelamento, o aplicativo levou 40 minutos para ser
>   atualizado via Internet.

Certamente o usuário desse cenário bem real ficou muito desapontado com o produto. A razão é bem simples: o produto parece saber mais do que ele, tirou completamente o controle dele sobre quando seria o melhor momento para fazer uma tarefa (atualização) que ele sequer solicitou. Pode ser algo importante, mas não para ele.

Apesar do comicidade nesse cenário, esse assunto é sério e muita gente se preocupa cada vez mais com isso em seus produtos (infelizmente não tantos como gostaríamos, ainda mais no Brasil - não sei em Portugal). Assim, o resumo prático é o seguinte:

- Tarefas longas que são iniciadas pelo usuário tendem a ser mais bem recebidas. Mas ainda assim é importante oferecer opções de cancelamento, adiamento ou execução em pano de fundo. O usuário precisa se sentir no controle da interação, seja na consideração de que vai fazer outra coisa enquanto a tarefa é executada, ou na consideração sobre desistir de sua execução.
- Tarefas longas que não são iniciadas pelo usuário devem ser realizadas com muito mais cuidado, de forma a reduzir o máximo possível o impacto em suas atividades. Se é algo que interrompe o serviço, deve ser realizada apenas com a anuência do usuário e deve lhe ser dada a opção de cancelar a qualquer momento. Dependendo da plataforma, útil oferecer mais de uma opção de execução ao usuário (por exemplo, para atualização pode ser feita via Internet ou via arquivo local em Pen-Drive, baixado de outro dispositivo).
- Sempre que possível, deve-se oferecer estimativas sobre o que já foi realizado e o que falta realizar. Essa informação é fundamental para o usuário se sentir no controle e decidir sobre esperar ou não, fazer outra coisa enquanto ou cancelar, etc. O uso de uma animação simples (sem informação de andamento e/ou estimativa de completude) é mais aceitável em tarefas solicitadas pelo usuário e cuja duração seja curta (*refresh* de tela, por exemplo).
- É muito útil avaliar o uso da sua aplicação com seus usuários, tanto em protótipos durante a fase de desenvolvimento como com a aplicação real durante a fase de uso. Deve-se ficar atento a qualquer comentário ruim em relação a uma interação desse tipo, pois ele pode apontar um problema maior quando experienciado por mais usuários.

Comment: Muito boa resposta.