# Substituto para o ProgressDialog

Tags: android

Nos meus apps utilizei o *Progress Dialog* porém li que ele está depreciado a partir da API O .

[De acordo com esse link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Queria saber qual componente pode ser substituto dele, pois eu utilizava da seguinte forma.

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Aguarde.",
            "Processando..!", true);
```

E em determinado parte do código onde eu saberia que já tinha sido processado, eu colocava

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Estava lendo sobre *Progress Bar* porém ela não trabalha dessa forma ou trabalha?

Comment: No que acompanho o pessoal esta usando a Progress Bar realmente, aqui tem um exemplo de um exercício super completo (em inglês) https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Progress-Bar-Custom-View mas vale a pena a leitura

Comment: @PauloH.Hartmann vou ler depois o tutorial. Usei agora pouco o progressBar (bolinha). Vou testar depois a progressBar (horizontal). Obrigado

Comment: Apenas uma nota sobre o uso da palavra: [**«depreciado» em inglês é «depreciated» e não «deprecated». A palavra «deprecated» que seria a correta para se referir a isto seria traduzida como «obsoleto», «desaprovado», «censurado»**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/3635)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Queria saber qual componente pode ser substituto dele (...).

O substituto sugerido é o [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html). Ambos, [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) e [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html), existem desde a versão inicial do Android.

> Estava lendo sobre Progress Bar porém ela não trabalha dessa forma ou trabalha?

Sim, se se refere à possibilidade de o iniciar e parar. A diferença é que um é um *dialog* enquanto o outro é exibido "dentro" do *layout*.

---

O ProgressDialog foi considerado obsoleto no Android O(Api Level 26) que, nesta data, é a última versão.
O facto de ter sido considerado obsoleto não implica que não o possa utilizar.

A principal razão, a meu ver, para o ProgressDialog ser considerado obsoleto, tem a ver com a experiência do usuário - a apresentação dum *dialog* limita a interacção do usuário, com a aplicação, enquanto a tarefa está a ser executada.

Veja a pergunta [Melhores práticas ao apresentar tela de loading em Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63561/2541), onde o [Luiz Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/73/luiz-vieira), na sua [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66746/2541), aborda a questão na perspectiva da "usabilidade".
Na minha [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63660/2541), à pergunta referida, encontra um exemplo da utilização do ProgressBar.

Comment: boa cara, me ajudou muito aqui. Usei o `progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` e quando carrega o procedimento usei o `progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. Obrigado